# Getting birthdays between next 15 days

Tags: angular, api, heroku, filter, loopback

I have my employees list and I want to use filter from loopback to get the emp details who's birthday is in next 15 days.

```
?filter={"where":{"birthday":{"between":["' + fromDate + 'T00:00:00.000Z","' + toDate + 'T23:59:00.000Z"]}}}
```

I am using this filter into my querystring. But it is checking with year also. I just want to check with month and date. any solution with loopback filter ?

Comment: With moments you can achieve this, use the isBetween method in moments then you will be fine

Comment: can I pass it to my loopback api ?

Comment: Offcourse, but it's recommendable to avoid pipe but it will still work